# How to map JPA entity identifiers to work on both Oracle and MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Currently, I am migrating my database from Oracle to Mysql. For a brief transition period, I want to support both databases. (at least read from both)

The main challenge I am facing is regarding primary key generation.

1. In Oracle, I am using sequences.

```java
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_SEQ", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ", allocationSize = 2)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQ")
    private Long id;
```

2. In Mysql I am using auto-increment (Oracle doesn't support it)

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

Is there a way I can set this strategy dynamically based on what DB is configured? I don't want to have a duplicate copy of models just for this purpose. Of course, let me know if I am headed in a sub-optimal direction.

Comment: How many entities do you have?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli 100+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use the [`TABLE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) generator as it's bad for performance.

Therefore, you should use [`SEQUENCE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/) startegy by default:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "sequence",
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "sequence",
        allocationSize = 10
    )
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity sake
}
```

and override the `SEQUENCE` with `IDENTITY` for MySQL using the XML mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1"
    >

    <package>com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.identifier.global</package>
    <entity class="Post" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

So, when you build the MySQL artifact, you need to deploy the supplied `orm.xml` that overrides the identifier strategies.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation SEQUENCE should also work with Databases that do not have sequences.

> 2.6.9. Using sequences
>
> For implementing database sequence-based identifier value generation
>   Hibernate makes use of its
>   org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator id generator. It is
>   important to note that SequenceStyleGenerator is capable of working
>   against databases that do not support sequences by switching to a
>   table as the underlying backing. This gives Hibernate a huge degree of
>   portability across databases while still maintaining consistent id
>   generation behavior (versus say choosing between SEQUENCE and
>   IDENTITY). This backing storage is completely transparent to the user.

**The drawback is that it will not use MySQL auto_increment but a database table.**

But as you need this for a limited time why not go that way and when you no longer need Oracle switch to auto_increment and IDENTITY.

Comment: Yeah, I will keep that as my fallback option if I can't find some better alternative. Thanks!!